# Should NuGet Spec detect dependencies?

Tags: teamcity

I've just run `nuget spec` in the folder where my .csproj file is and it didn't write the dependencies to the .nuspec file. Should it have?

The solution has package restore enabled and builds fine on TeamCity.

Comment: Does it have any package dependencies (packages.config)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `nuget spec` does *not* automatically include dependencies to other NuGet packages in your project. However, running `nuget pack MyProject.csproj` when you also have a nuspec-file will result in a nupkg-file where NuGet packages used in *MyProject* are included as dependencies in your package.

It is also worth noting that as of v2.5 (which is planned to be released some time at the end of April I believe), you'll also have the option to additionally include dependencies to other projects in your solution that also have nuspec-files:

> When building a package from a project, when
>   -IncludeReferencedProjects is specified, projects  referenced by the project are either added as a dependency of the package, if nuspec
>   file exists, or are added into the package if nuspec file doesn't
>   exist.

See [changelog.txt](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/10d5d38151489ce053b314ed440bdbfbc30c595f#changelog.txt) for v2.5 for details.

Comment: -IncludeReferencedProjects does not do this

Comment: I can't get it to do this either, I opened an issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5720